# Why does an RPC call fail in a C program called from Groovy on Linux?

Tags: linux, groovy, rpc, sunrpc

We have a program, written in C, that uses RPC to communicate with another program (also written in C) on the same Linux server (in some production setups, the second C program would on another machine, therefore RPC instead of IPC).

When called from other C programs, CRON or the command line, it works as expected and has been doing so for many years, so it's safe to say it generally works.

The same program, called from a Groovy script, fails, apparently with network problems.

In the C program, `svc_register(xprt, prognum, versnum, dispatch, protocol)` succeeds, but then

- on the RPC server after request: `clnttcp_create` fails with "connection refused"
- on the RPC client waiting for reply: `select` on `svc_fdset` fails with `EBADF`

Groovy program (just for completeness, not much to see here):

```
[ "myprogram", "someoption", "someprogram" ].execute()
```

What could we try to pinpoint and fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, calling RPC based C-programs from Groovy does indeed work.

The problem could be narrowed down to the issue that "(int)sysconf (_SC_OPEN_MAX)", which is used to determine the number of fds in svc_fdset (a structure used to get replies from rpc-requests) does fail in case of being used by a C program called from Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Run the program through `strace`, to see what system call(s) is/are failing.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `myprogram` has output or waits for input. If you don't read the output or close the input, then it will hang, leading to timeouts in the RPC call. Create a thread which reads `in` and `err` of `myprogram` and close `out`:

```
def p = [ "myprogram", "someoption", "someprogram" ].execute()
p.out.close()
p.consumeProcessOutput()
```